# What is causing: Invalid input. ld: library not found for -lclang_rt.ios

Tags: air

I'm trying to publish an .ipa file using Adobe AIR via Animate and have started getting this error:

```
Invalid input.

ld: library not found for -lclang_rt.ios
```

Would anyone have an idea what this might be related to?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To update the SDK you will need to copy the library libclang_rt.ios.a into your AIR SDK and place it at: [AIR_SDK]/lib/aot/lib

You can grab the library file here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kvhk8yxxomy3tpn/libclang_rt.ios.a?dl=0

Or from your Xcode installation:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/*/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.ios.a

If you don’t do this correctly, you will see something like the following error when packaging:

ld: library not found for -lclang_rt.ios
Compilation failed while executing : ld64